# Prove $\frac{ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)}{ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)}=0$ $⟹\ t=i\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right),\ n\ ∈\ Z$

Tags: zeta-functions

**Do I prove it works?**

$$\frac{ζ\left(x\right)}{ζ\left(1-x\right)}=\frac{2^{\left(x-1\right)}\pi^{x}\csc\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi\left(1-x\right)\right)\right)}{Γ(x)}=\frac{2^{\left(x-1\right)}\pi^{x}\csc\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi\left(1-x\right)\right)\right)}{\left(x-1\right)!}$$
$$⟹\frac{ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)}{ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)}=\frac{2^{\left(it-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\pi^{\frac{1}{2}+it}\csc\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)\right)\right)}{\left(it-\frac{1}{2}\right)!}$$
$$⟹\left(it-\frac{1}{2}\right)!=\frac{2^{\left(it-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\pi^{\frac{1}{2}+it}\csc\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)\right)\right)}{ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)}ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)$$
$$⟹\left(\operatorname{abs}\left(\left(it-\frac{1}{2}\right)!\right)\right)^{2}=\left(\operatorname{abs}\left(\frac{2^{\left(it-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\pi^{\frac{1}{2}+it}\csc\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)\right)\right)}{ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)}ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)\right)\right)^{2}$$
$$\left(\operatorname{abs}\left(\left(it-\frac{1}{2}\right)!\right)\right)^{2}=\frac{\pi}{\cosh\left(\pi t\right)}$$
$$⟹\left(\operatorname{abs}\left(\frac{2^{\left(it-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\pi^{\frac{1}{2}+it}\csc\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)\right)\right)}{ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)}ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)\right)\right)^{2}=\frac{\pi}{\cosh\left(\pi t\right)}$$
$$⟹\left(\operatorname{abs}\left(\frac{ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)}{2^{\left(it-\frac{1}{2}\right)}\pi^{\frac{1}{2}+it}\csc\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\pi\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)\right)\right)ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)}\right)\right)^{2}=\frac{\cosh\left(\pi t\right)}{\pi}$$
$$\frac{ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)}{ζ\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)}=0$$
$$⟹\frac{\cosh\left(\pi t\right)}{\pi}=0\ ⟹\ t=i\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right),\ n\ ∈\ Z$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For context, see the [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4741470/prove-%ce%b6-left-2x-right-0-%e2%9f%b9-x-%e2%88%88-%e2%84%95). You should edit before posting a new question.